# Recover files in Windows 7 after a botched batch move that rewrote file names

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, file-recovery

My goal was to flatten a complex directory.  I went to the complex directory and searched for all files with `*` in the search box.  I sorted the results by file type and selected all the files -- in other words, I excluded the folder names.  I should have done a COPY at this point -- but I did a CUT (control x) and then pasted into the new target (flat) directory.  Turns out there were many files with the same names.  Accidentally I said "yes" to the replace files with same name question ("Would you like to replace the existing file").

Is there a way to recover the missing files?

Comment: from your backup, ideally.

Comment: @Tetsujin - If I had a back-up of that folder... would I be asking?  (These files aren't high priority -- those are all backed up -- nevertheless if I can recover them that would be nice.)

Comment: Then it's down to whatever file-scraper software you prefer. There's no 'undelete' button, if that's what you're asking.